# Rails one line conditional failing with syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I am doing simple conditionals, but probably missing something obvious.

This code fails with: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' redirect_f ? redirect_to root_url : return redirect_f ^

```
def check_permissions(redirect_f = true)
    unless current_user 
        redirect_f ? redirect_to root_url : return redirect_f
    end
end
```

But this one works correctly:

```
def check_permissions(redirect_f = true)
    unless current_user 
        if redirect_f 
            redirect_to root_url 
        else
            return redirect_f
        end
    end
end
```

From what I know, both do the same and syntax is correct, but I want to use the first one. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `(` and `)` because ruby cannot recognise what exactly do you mean

```
unless current_user 
    redirect_f ? redirect_to(root_url) : return(redirect_f)
end
```

Comment: thanks, this also seems to work: redirect_f ? (redirect_to root_url) : (return redirect_f)

Comment: @Aulait yes it is :)